# how to merge video file one by one

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avfoundation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merge Two Video files in iPhone Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071029/merge-two-video-files-in-iphone-application)

I have download 40mb video file from server in multiple split(2mb). i'm using `NSURLConnection` i want to make that 20 split as a single video file. how to do that is there any API in iphone framework can some one explain me with code.
here is my connectionDidFinishLoading method

```
 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                      filePath];
[contentData writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];

}
```

if i write like this i got only last split file. i mean 2mb data only some one guide me how to do that?

Comment: @Abizern There they have used AVAsset, but this user is trying to merge using File handler, so two different scenario

Comment: @KingofBliss Regardless of the method that he's shown here - the solution is in the other SO post.

Comment: @Abizern i tried file handler. file will download fully but its showing "the movie's file format isn't recognized"

Comment: I think this may be useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002979/downloading-a-large-file-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Im not sure whether writeToFile works in this scenario,**

But to add a file in appending mode use the following code,

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *documentTXTPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Notes.txt"];
NSString *savedString = textview.text;
NSFileHandle *myHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:logPath];
[myHandle seekToEndOfFile];
[myHandle writeData:[savedString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Remove the code,

```
[contentData writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
```

Comment: this is not a string file bro

Comment: Thats what i mentioned that Im not sure it will work in this scenario for video

Comment: My code is for creating a text file in appending mode.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void) mergeVideos{
///... after getting hold or your assets....firstAsset, secondAsset

AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *firstTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo 
                                                                  preferredTracfirst:kCMPersistentTracfirst_Invalid];
[firstTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration) 
                    ofTrack:[[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] 
                     atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *secondTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo 
                                                                   preferredTracfirst:kCMPersistentTracfirst_Invalid];

[secondTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, secondAsset.duration)
                     ofTrack:[[secondAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] 
                      atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];    

[secondTrack setPreferredTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.25f,0.25f)]; 
}
```